# WebView is removed from View when it's subview's tag is zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, webview, uibutton

My code has bunch of buttons added to `webview.scrollview` all of them has different tags but when I try to remove the one with the tag number `0` web view is also removed from view.

When I add web view to `self.view` I set web view's tag `webView.tag=121212;` and `webView.scrollView.tag=121211;`

then I call

```
- (void)removeButtonFromScrollView:(NSInteger)butonTag
{
    [(UIButton*)[webView.scrollView viewWithTag:butonTag]  removeFromSuperview];
}
```

How can I make sure only button is removed from web view, not web view itself.

Comment: Every view has a default tag of 0. Never use 0 as an explicit tag. Start with 1 or some other value.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use tag with `0` value. If you generating tags, save them somewhere to check later.

For example you can you `NSMutableSet`, it can contain only unique value. Or just try to get view with this tag.

```
if ([self.view viewWithTag:tag]) {
 // don't use it, generate another one
}
```